# Javascript обработка input radio

Tags: javascript

```
<label><input type="radio" name="dostavka" value="moskva"> Москва</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="dostavka" value="piter"> Санкт-Петербург</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="dostavka" value="vladik"> Владивосток</label>
<div id="summa_tovarov">1000</div>
<div id="itogo"></div>
```

Помогите динамически в элементе itogo складывать сумму товаров summa_tovarov и стоимость доставки элементов радио dostavka

в js заранее определить стоимость доставки в каждый регион

Comment: [посмотрите сюда](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#homework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я конечно не очень хорошо знаю еще javascript и jquery, но в простейшем случае будет так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( 
        function() 
        {

           $("input[name=dostavka]").live("change", function()
           {
           var sum = 0;
           sum = parseInt(document.getElementById("summa_tovarov").innerHTML);
           var checkElements=document.getElementsByName("dostavka");
              for(var i=0; i<checkElements.length; i++)
              {
                checkElement = checkElements[i];
                if (checkElement.checked==1)
                {
                  sum = sum + parseInt(checkElement.value);
                }  
              }
              document.getElementById("itogo").innerHTML = sum;
            }  
               );
        }

        );
    </script>

    <input type="radio" name="dostavka" value="300" id="moskva"> <label for="moskva">Москва</label>
    <input type="radio" name="dostavka" value="400" id="piter"> <label for="piter">Санкт-Петербург</label>
    <input type="radio" name="dostavka" value="500" id="vladik"> <label for="vladik">Владивосток</label>

    <div id="summa_tovarov">1000</div>

    <div id="itogo"></div>
```

Вот ссылка на рабочий вариант. http://jsfiddle.net/XPp6e/

Если кто заметил неточности, поправьте меня.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Почему-то выводит не 1500 а 1000500. Логику немного понял. Можно немного скоректировать под последную версию моего вопроса, я в value вставил название региона, так проще будет в дальнейшем обрабатывать форму мне через php, задать по умолчанию стоимость доставки:
var moskva = 300;
var piter = 400;
var vladik = 500;

Comment: Используй parseInt. Я забыл просто добавить его. Оно в виде строки складывает значения. Вот поправка http://jsfiddle.net/XPp6e/1/ Отметь ответ мой как правильный! Буду благодарен!

Comment: В любом случае ты помог мне решить мой вопрос, спасибо. Как быстр опроясняется js для меня :) Я уже допилил и второй вариант.

Comment: Ну тогда удачи). Рад был помочь)

Comment: Очень понравился Ваш вариант реализации данного вопроса. Он почти то что мне нужно, т.к. содержит часть необходимого мне. Но для финальной реализации моего проекта нужно результат, выводимый в <div id="itogo"></div> - само его значение - сделать переменной PHP, для последующего использования. Это возможно? Моя цель - сохранить в текстовый файл результат вычисления. Возможно ли это сделать силами Javascript?