# Javascript обработка input radio с выводом результата в текстовый файл или переменную PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Есть похожий вопрос [Javascript обработка input radio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/275219/javascript-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-input-radio), который я взял за основу, но меня интересует возможность вывода значения во внешний файл или переменную PHP. Это вообще возможно сделать силами Javascript?

Comment: отправив запрос на сервер

Comment: Если не трудно, можете уточнить поподробнее - как это делается?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch